# Can't boot Windows 10 after linux install

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, mx-linux

[Just installed MX-Linux 19](https://mxlinux.org/current-release-features/) 64-bit on a [Thinkpad T420](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t420?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=T420%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)) which already had Windows 10 Pro installed; however, [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) does not show Windows Boot Manager or Windows anything as an option to boot. I was booting from /dev/sdb, an mSATA card; /dev/sda is a newly installed 2.5" SATA-III drive.

`sudo os-prober` returns **/dev/sdb1:Windows 10:Windows:chain**

`sudo parted -l` returns:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512GB  512GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA KINGSTON SUV500M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  608MB  607MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      608MB   315GB  315GB  primary  ntfs
 3      315GB   480GB  165GB  primary  ext4
```

How do I troubleshoot the absence of Windows as a menu choice in GRUB2?

Comment: @roaima So the boot flag should be in /dev/sdb3 where I installed Linux?

Comment: Did you already try running: `sudo update-grub`